# interactive shell vs editor

Tags: python, shell, editor

I tried this code in the editor:

```
name = "Sophie"
for i in name:
  print(f"***{i}***")
```

giving this result

```
***S***
***o***
***p***
***h***
***i***
***e***
```

but the same entry in the interactive shell gives an error:

```
>>> name = "Sophie"
>>> for i in name:
... print(f"***{i}***")
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(f"***{i}***")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `IndentationError`  means you haven't indented the code.

Comment: The secondary prompt `...` doesn't count towards indentation. Column 0, as far as the parser is concerned, is the column where `for` begins.

Answer (score -1):

```py
>>> name = "Sophie"
>>> for i in name:
... <try press tab in here>print(f"***{i}***")
```

You miss that indentation.

Comment: I suggest to put 4-spaces instead of tabs